# Не приходит file_id

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram

Прописал команду и у меня не приходит id файла, как его можно ещё получить и почему не приходит?

```
  import telebot
import config

client = telebot.TeleBot(config.token['token'])

@client.message_handler(commands = ['test'])
def find_file_ids(message):
    for file in os.listdir('misic/'):
        if file.split('.')[-1] == 'ogg':
            f = open('music/'+file, 'rb')
            msg = client.send_voice(message.chat.id, f, None)
            client.send_message(message.chat.id, msg.voice.file_id, reply_to_message_id = msg.message_id)
        time.sleep(3)



client.polling(none_stop = True, interval = 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Смущает эта строчка:

```
client = telebot.TeleBot(config.token['token'])
```

Если вы пошли по примерам, которые я посоветовал, то там иначе:

```
client = telebot.TeleBot(config.token)
```